# Exclude IB object value from strings file

Tags: xcode, localization, interface-builder

Can I exclude value of object in Interface Builder of strings file ?

I don't want localize static value of `UILabel` or `UIButton` because I override its value programatically.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

UILabels and UIButtons don't need to contain text in Interface Builder. You can leave them blank and populate them with the strings you want programmatically.

Comment: Yes, but they are still exported.